# How to whitelist http header in a shiny application using shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I want to whitelist http header that a proxy is sending for authentification. I am aware that you would usually use some sort of server.conf file. However, as far as I understood, you can't really access this file in a shinyapps.io-container. Any thoughts / ideas or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Can you give more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish? Are you saying that a header is currently being removed by the shiny application? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: My goal is to check whether headers have a certain value, so I can confirm that the request to my shiny app is valid and is coming from the proxy. I honestly don't know, how I should provide a reproducible example for this problem. There are custom headers sent by the proxy and I want to read them. Unfortunately they are not available once I try to access them via the session argument.